# Catch validation status of specific model field

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-validation

Im newbie in asp.NET, and im trying to understand some things about Models and Validations...

Im using my company html/css framework, and it works validation in this way:

```
<div class="input-group [validation status here]">
    <label for="something">Something</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="something" id ="something" placeholder="Stuff"/>
    <div class="validation-info">[validation info here]</div>
</div>
```

In PHP its easy to set a validation status, only replaces [validation status here] to `<?=status;?>` and works nice. Now, in .NET im using `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Field)` and automatically creates classes, data attributes and sets over input.

I'm reading about this and closest solution is with JQuery. I want a solution directly in .net.

Then, my question is: Its possible to catch a specific field status in server side like php?:

```
<div class="input-group @SomeFunctionToCatchValidationStatus">
    <label for="something">Something</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="something" id ="something" placeholder="Stuff"/>
    <div class="validation-info">@SomeFunctionToCatchValidationMessage</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `EditorFor` have a `TextBoxFor` and separate `ValidationMessageFor`.

Comment: @WiktorZychla But, is same thing; i cant set "error","success" over a parent input-group element. I want to catch a validation status to put it in parent.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand what you are up to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `ModelState.IsValidField("Field")`. We can put it Controller, for example, in `ViewBag.ModelState` variable and catch it directly in view with a conditional:

```
<div class="input-group @((!ViewBag.ModelState.IsValidField("something"))?"error":"")">
    <label for="something">Something</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="something" id ="something" placeholder="Stuff"/>
    <div class="validation-info">[validation info here]</div>
</div>
```